# Can you help me to understand Multi-tone FSK, and how I can implement it?

Tags: modulation, fsk

Any paper, book, Matlab file... that you would recommend.

Thanks.

Comment: ARRL Handbook.  Or RSGB Handbook.

Comment: @TimWescott, thanks

Comment: @TimWescott Can you please turn this into an answer so that Qasim Khalaf could then accept it and thus close this question gracefully?